# Why I can not pass the app to the controller in Express 4?

Tags: node.js, express

since I have start my first project, i was working on it and use express 4. but when I pass the app.locals to the controller, it was a empty object. I do not know what to do now,please help.

Here is my project structure:

app (home directory)

-->controller(folder)
---->webroot.js

-->router(folder)
----> index.js

-->app.js

## app.js

important part:

```
...  
app.set('x', '123')
...   
module.exports = app;
```

## router/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
/*controllers here*/
var webroot = require('../controllers/webroot')

var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', webroot.index);
```

## controller/webroot.js

```
var app = require('../app');

console.log(app.get('x'))  //Object #<Object> has no method 'get'

exports.index = function(req,res){
    //code here
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to a [cycle of dependencies](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

```
app.js -> router/index.js -> controllers/webroot.js -> app.js -> ...
```

That is, assuming `app.js` includes another "*important part*" of requiring `router/index`, such as.

```
// ...
app.use(require('./router'));
// ...
app.locals.title = '123';
// ...
module.exports = app;
```

In handling cycles, Node.js will have only executed a portion of `app.js` when `webroot.js` requires `app.js` it again, which is only up to the inclusion of `router/index.js`.

---

To work with the cycle, you'll want to order the statements so enough of `app.js` is executed before starting the cycle:

```
// ...

// modify shared state
app.locals.title = '123';

// then load dependencies with cycles
app.use(require('./router'));

// ...
```

Comment: In fact, I just want to add `app.set('x','123')` in `app.js` and get it in `webroot.js`.but app.get('x') won't work becuz app can not pass to webroot

Comment: @RyanYiada At what point does `webroot` need to use `app.get('x')`? If it's within a route handler, `req.app.get('x')` can be used. The `req.app` property isn't listed in the API, but is defined.

Comment: see this code:`var User = app.get('models').User;` If I can not use `app.get`,then what should i use ?

Comment: @RyanYiada Generally, you can just `require('./models')` as needed without needing `app` -- similar to the multiple `require('express')`. [The module will be cached](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), so each `require()` of it will return the same instance.

Comment: but that artical said, it was not a best idea. It says:"That means that using require('./models') to get the models may create more than one connection to the database. "

Comment: @RyanYiada That's referring to the [caveat](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats) that caching is based on full path of the module. You only get multiple instances and, in this case, multiple open connections if you have multiple `model.js` at different paths that may be required.

Comment: so I only need to do is `require('./models')` and will not connect database multiple times, right?

Comment: @RyanYiada Yeah, especially with relative paths within your own project, you should be good. — Where the caveat is more of a concern is with [modules in `node_modules` folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders), when the lookup is slightly automated. With the rather common deep-nesting of package dependencies, you can rather easily end up with multiple copies of the same module installed. Each copy gets its own cache. [`npm dedupe`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-dedupe.html) can help to a degree with this.